# Flip UIView with thickness (like iBooks)

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm making a reversi clone, and trying to add some thickness when I flip the buttons (Like iBook transition view).

Right now, I use this code to flip the buttons on the board:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:whiteView toView:blackView duration:0.5f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
 completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

I found a project on github that have implemented this, but I can't get it to work with a child view added to the main viewController.

How do you add the transition to just flip a view, and not transition to a new viewController?

Thanks in advance

https://github.com/epatel/EPGLTransitionView